# Reactjs how to change data in sibling component from a map function?

Tags: reactjs

I have App.js file which renders a component A and component B. B is a list so I use a map function to render component C. Their relationship is like this:

```
App.js renders
  - A
  - B which renders multiple C in a map function
```

Now I need to update data in A when I click on a component C, which contains a event method call `onTouchTap`. Component C basically just display a username. The text in A will be updated with the username I click in component C. But I don't know how to make that happen.

In B, I render the list as follows:

```
return (
    <div>
      <List>
        this.props.users.map((user, i) => {
          return <C onTouchTap={this.props.onUsernameClick} />
        }
      </List>
    </div>
   );
```

In App.js, I render it as follows:

```
  <div>
    <A text={this.state.text} />
    <B users={this.state.users} onUsernameClick={this.handleUsernameClick} />
  </div>
```

But in this way I can't pass in the parameter `user` and `i` so I can't update the text of A correctly with the right username click.

What is the solution?

Comment: The [Redux Architecture](http://redux.js.org/) may be something you want to look at.

Comment: @jrenk Thanks I understand that. However I am just trying out the possibility here using React without Redux. Redux seems overkill right now but I will look into it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make C a component and use a local clickHandler like so;
  clickHandler = () => { this.props.handleUsernameClick(this.props.user, this.props.index); };

Comment: Wher are the props.user and props.index from? `user` and `i` are now inside the map function.

Comment: Pass them along in the map function of B.

Answer (score 0):

In C, add an onClick event handler and call `onUsernameClick(clickedUsername)` passing the username that was clicked back to the passed function.
In App, implement handleUsernameClick to receive the passed username and set the state with this value which will be passed to A.

```
handleUsernameClick(clickedUsername){ this.setState(text:clickedUsername)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an anonymous function and call `onUsernameClick` with the parameters `event`,`user`, `i` inside the anonymous function.

Hope this helps!

```
return (
    <div>
      <List>
        this.props.users.map((user, i) => {
          return <C onTouchTap={(event) => this.props.onUsernameClick(event, user, i)} />
        }
      </List>
    </div>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up binding the onUsernameClick with some parameters, like this:

```
return <C onTouchTap={this.props.onUsernameClick.bind(this, user)} />
```

Then in App.js,

```
<B users={this.state.users} onUsernameClick={this.handleUsernameClick.bind(this)} />
```

Then in method `handleUsernameClick` I set the state in the main component in App.js:

```
handleUsernameClick(user) {
    this.setState({
      text: user.name
    });
  }
```

Next step is to respond to the props change in component A, remember I have rendered App.js as :

```
  <div>
    <A text={this.state.text} />
    <B users={this.state.users} onUsernameClick={this.handleUsernameClick.bind(this)} />
  </div>
```

So A's props `text` will be changed as per the change of the `text` state in `App.js`.

I need to add a method name `componentWillReceiveProps` in component A:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.text !== nextProps.text) {
        // respond to the props change here
    }
  }
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` will take action every time A's props are changed in its parent component.

In this way I am able to make changes in sibling components based on the events in the map function of current component's child components. My scenario is that when I click on a list item in a list the text of the textarea will be updated with the list item name.